# Trying to call a Web Service but issue occurs

Tags: c#, web-services

I'm trying to call a webservice but following issue occurred earlier it was working fine but now this error is arising any exact idea what is happening.

> Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server machine failed.
>
> The visual studio 2015 remote debugger (MSVSMON.exe) does not appear to be running on the remote computer.This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see help for assistance on configuring remote debugging.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have exception handling + logging at the web service?

Comment: Is the error message not explicitly clear? Have you checked the remote debugging service is running and if so a firewall isn't blocking communication to it?

Comment: Issue has been been resolved actually application rights has been changed